# What is the maximum number of characters for a host-name in Unix?

Tags: c, unix, max, hostname

I am wondering what is the maximum number of characters for a host-name in a Unix system. In addition is there any defined variable that can be used in Unix programming to call that number? (i.e. number of characters allowed for a host-name).

I am programming in C.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can usually type:

```
getconf HOST_NAME_MAX
```

In addition, you can generally include `limits.h` to your application and read the value of the define.

While the POSIX standard says it is guaranteed not to exceed 255 bytes, that does not necessarily mean that each implementation will adhere to that.

`man gethostname` on your platform to get more detailed information.

Comment: On Linux (glibc?), `unistd.h` is insufficient, you have to include `limits.h`.

Comment: on many versions of linux (e.g. trusty) you can't set hostname > 64 chars

Comment: looks like no way to update a comment, but it is 64 as of kernel 4.13 : https://github.com/torvalds/linux/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=__NEW_UTS_LEN&type=

Answer (score 71):

**tl;dr**:

Code should deal with hostnames up to 255 bytes long;
administrators should keep hostname length (excluding domain) within 19 bytes,
and domain name length (excluding hostnames) within 23 bytes.

- Hostnames can be as long as **255** bytes (some systems may limit them to 64)
- Hostnames used in DNS can be as long as **253** bytes
  as a *fully qualified domain name* (FQDN=`host.example.com`), in which case:

  - The first DNS label (removing `.` and anything after it from the hostname)
    can only be up to **63** bytes
  - The 253 byte limit applies to the *entire* FQDN,
    even if only the first label is used for the Unix hostname
- Hostnames used in e-mail addresses should not exceed **245** bytes
  (for traditional 8 character username limit)
  or **221** bytes (modern maximum username length of 32)
  as a fully qualified domain name
- Hostnames used for server TLS/SSL certificates should not exceed **64** bytes
  as a fully qualified domain name
- Hostnames used for e-mail addresses in OpenSSL-generated certificates
  should not exceed **31** bytes (for traditional 8 character username limit)
  as a fully qualified domain name (usernames longer than 8 reduce this limit)
- If there are non-ASCII characters in the hostname subtract **4**
  for each non-ASCII domain label (part between `.` characters)
  from all the above limits, and subtract an additional 1-2 bytes
  (not including UTF-8 encoding overhead of 1-2 more bytes per character)
  for each non-ASCII character.

Long version:

As @Michael says, POSIX hostnames are generally limited to 255 bytes, and as @zrvan points out, DNS limits the length of each label in [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) - however, that limit is actually **63** (both in [RFC 1035 section 2.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-2.3.1) and as clarified in [RFC 2181 section 11](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181#section-11)).

There are other limits that come into play when you are using hostnames that will be used in DNS, as hostnames in SSL certificates or e-mail addresses.

First, the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) length limit is 255 octets when represented in the DNS protocol as

> "a series of labels, ... terminated by a label of length zero. ... A label consists of a length octet followed by that number of octets representing the name itself"

- [MSDN Blog "The Old New Thing"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120412-00/?p=7873) (quoting RFC 1035, with useful illustration)

With these length prefixes (including the one for the final length zero label), the actual limit for a fully qualified domain name is **253** bytes.

If your hostname will also be used as the DNS name for a server for which you need a TLS/SSL certificate, there is a much shorter limit that will affect you.
[Appendix A.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#appendix-A.1) of RFC 5280 and its predecessor RFCs 3280 and 2459 specify Upper Bounds for different fields of an X.509 certificate; the `ub-common-name-length` limit for the Common Name field, which for server certificates is the server's fully qualified domain name, is **64** bytes.

If you use OpenSSL to generate an SSL certificate with an e-mail address field more than 40 bytes long, you will see this error:

> string is too long, it needs to be less than  40 bytes long

If a hostname will be used in e-mail addresses for OpenSSL-generated certificates, the `@` and username will also need to fit within 40 bytes (the "less than" in the error should really be "no more than"), which for a maximum username length of 8 bytes, implies a maximum hostname FQDN length of **31** bytes.  If the maximum username length is longer than 8 bytes, the maximum hostname length is decreased accordingly - [the modern Linux limit of 32](https://serverfault.com/a/294122) would give a maximum FQDN length of **7** that is impractical, even for URL shortening services like bit.ly.

The OpenSSL choice of a 40 as the length limit for an e-mail address X.509 subject alternative name may have been chosen for compatibility with the shortest possible alternative name syntax, E.163-4 (for telephone numbers), and it is likely that TLS/SSL implementations (perhaps even including OpenSSL) support *use* of certificates with longer e-mail addresses.  There is a separate upper bound (`ub-emailaddress-length`) of 128 bytes in RFC 3280, increased to 255 bytes in RFC 5280; this is actually for another, legacy embedding of e-mail addresses in X.509 certificates, but it would not be surprising if many implementations use that upper bound for rfc822Address e-mail IA5Strings as well.

While OpenSSL could increase this limit in the future, there is no issue for this in the [OpenSSL Request Tracker](http://rt.openssl.org/?user=guest&pass=guest), and it seems unlikely to be changed.

Even if you don't use TLS/SSL, the [maximum e-mail address length of 254](https://stackoverflow.com/a/574698/18829) implies a maximum hostname FQDN length of **245** bytes for a traditional 8 byte username limit; or **221** bytes for a modern maximum username length limit of 32.

Taking the minimum of all these maximums and a [2012 median .com domain length of 11](http://datagenetics.com/blog/march22012/) (coincidentally the exact length of example.com), and you get a maximum first label hostname length of **19** bytes for a 40 byte e-mail address like
`useruser@REALLY-GETTING-LONG.example.com`.

If all your e-mail addresses are mapped to a top-level domain name with MX records and MTA address rewriting, assuming a more reasonable username/alias length limit of 16, you get a maximum domain name length of **23** bytes for a 40 byte e-mail address like `useruseruseruser@NOT-SO-LONG.EXAMPLE.COM`.

Finally, non-ASCII hostnames require IDN (internationalized domain name) encoding
for use with DNS; this involves an encoding with a 4 character `xn--` prefix for each domain label with non-ASCII characters, and an expansion of 1-2 bytes for each non-ASCII character (in addition to the larger size resulting from UTF-8 encoding). If your hostname has non-ASCII characters, you need to reduce all of the above limits accordingly.

Answer (score 21):

According to [RFC 1035](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) the length of a FQDN is limited to 255 characters, and each label (node delimited by a dot in the hostname) is limited to 63 characters, so in effect the limit you're after is 63.

You can get this value by running `getconf HOST_NAME_MAX` in the terminal.

Answer (score 13):

Hostnames are generally [limited to 255 bytes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/gethostname.html). `HOST_NAME_MAX` (or `_POSIX_HOST_NAME_MAX`) defined in `<limits.h>` will contain the specific value.

Comment: They are limited to that, but that doesn't mean that each implementation will set it's limit to that.  You still need to look at how it's defined in the HOST_NAME_MAX definition.  e.g. on my FreeBSD machine, it's 255, but on my linux host: getconf HOST_NAME_MAX
64

Answer (score 3):

Here's some sample code that puts it all together:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char host[HOST_NAME_MAX + 1];

host[HOST_NAME_MAX] = 0;

if (gethostname(host, sizeof(host) - 1) == 0)
{
    printf("hostname is %s\n", host);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Git 2.13 (Q2 2017) illustrates that name length limit in C, and reminds that  POSIX does not specify whether the buffer will be null-terminated.
It introduces a new function, `xgethostname()`, which ensures that there is always a `\0` at the end of the buffer.

See [commit 5781a9a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5781a9a2703e96b01587bb95ceebcc53f2cee91c) (18 Apr 2017) by [David Turner (`csusbdt`)](https://github.com/csusbdt).
<sup>(Merged by [David Turner -- `csusbdt` --](https://github.com/csusbdt) in [commit 5781a9a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5781a9a2703e96b01587bb95ceebcc53f2cee91c), 19 Apr 2017)</sup>

> ### use `HOST_NAME_MAX` to size buffers for gethostname(2)
>
> `POSIX` limits the length of host names to `HOST_NAME_MAX`.
>   Export the [fallback definition from `daemon.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/695dffe2efa53b9628e7811dbe33447a8014fd77) and use this constant to make all buffers used with gethostname(2) big enough for any possible result
>   and a terminating `NUL`.