# .net Uri class does not support URLs longer than 263 characters

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

AFAIK anything up to 2000 characters ought to be supported.

Reproduction:

```
var s = "http://www."
+ string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("a", 249))
+ ".com";

new Uri(s, UriKind.Absolute);
```

One letter shorter one is being parsed with no issue:

```
var s = "http://www."
+ string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("a", 248))
+ ".com";
```

The Uri class code was originated in 2003 and is carried over to .net standard / core. Does MS still claim 255 characters for path / URI is enough for everybody's needs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to create an Uri with a *hostname* of more than 255 characters. [255 is the max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724954/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-characters-for-a-host-name-in-unix).

This is also reflected in the exception message:

> Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.

So this one is not to blame on Microsoft.

Comment: I intended the words "exception message" to link to [this ideone repro](https://www.ideone.com/mRmM5O) that includes the exception message, but the system won't let me because then I'll have to repeat the OP's code.