# By what application is the domain name's length restricted by, and can this be changed if it is a different DNS implementation?

Tags: dns, domain-name

I'm currently implementing a decentralized DNS, and am wondering if a domain name character limit is specific to the storage of DNS records

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name)

> The full domain name may not exceed a total length of 255 characters

But then below it also says

> In practice, some domain registries may have shorter limits.

I've also looked at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8718510/453438) which mentions -

> My understanding is that the 255-character limit is to be considered
>   after the IDNA conversion.
>
> **This is because DNS records have this character limit**...

Is this true, and if so, does this mean my implementation can resolve domains with larger than 256 chars?

Comment: Define "_resolve_" ? You make an authoritative server, recursive resolver, DNS client or what ?

Comment: @Sandman4 I'm making an authoritative server, and in this context, resolve means to resolve the domain to the IP Address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thi is an RFC document you need:
http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1035.html

According to this different DNS records has it's own limit.

Probably you shouldn't think about a particular software or different practices, you just should look to an appropriate document (rfc specification).

Answer (score 1):

There are two limits:

- 255 character total length - this is arbitrary "To simplify implementations" (section 3.1 of RFC 1035)
- 63 characters per label - this is fixed by the 6 bit length field

There's nothing intrinsic in the *wire format* of DNS that limits names to 255 characters, but all DNS implementations should support up to that limit *and no more*.